# Solving Bitcoin core's 'ActivateBestChain failed'

Tags: bitcoin-core, testnet

I'm running bitcoin core version 0.16.2 on the **Testnet** and realized that it had stopped receving blocks after the [1414433](https://testnet.blockchain.info/block-index/5355357/00000000210004840364b52bc5e455d888f164e4264a4fec06a514b67e9d5722).

I tried running bitcoin core with options `-reindex` and `-reindex-chainstate` without success.

I have delete all the data and restarted syncing again, but ended up in the same problem

*PS: I am running in pruned mode*

What I've encountered in the debug.log is:

```
2018-09-28 16:43:38 UpdateTip: new best=00000000cb7df9801f21ccb4192844281d7da224d2213514050a8ad9a6d9ec7e height=1414432 version=0x20000000 log2_work=71.629388 tx=47735936 date='2018-09-27 03:27:30' progress=0.999747 cache=81.4MiB(531804txo)
2018-09-28 16:43:38 UpdateTip: new best=00000000210004840364b52bc5e455d888f164e4264a4fec06a514b67e9d5722 height=1414433 version=0x20000000 log2_work=71.629388 tx=47735938 date='2018-09-27 04:03:19' progress=0.999751 cache=81.4MiB(531807txo)
2018-09-28 16:43:38 ERROR: DisconnectTip(): DisconnectBlock 00000000210004840364b52bc5e455d888f164e4264a4fec06a514b67e9d5722 failed
2018-09-28 16:43:38 ERROR: ProcessNewBlock: ActivateBestChain failed
2018-09-28 16:43:39 ERROR: DisconnectTip(): DisconnectBlock 00000000210004840364b52bc5e455d888f164e4264a4fec06a514b67e9d5722 failed
2018-09-28 16:43:39 ERROR: ProcessNewBlock: ActivateBestChain failed`

[...]

2018-09-28 16:56:17 connect() to 78.47.24.41:18333 failed after select(): Connection refused (111)
2018-09-28 16:56:44 connect() to [2001:0:5ef5:79fd:38b6:55d:3788:c387]:18333 failed: Network is unreachable (101)
2018-09-28 17:01:12 ERROR: DisconnectTip(): DisconnectBlock 00000000210004840364b52bc5e455d888f164e4264a4fec06a514b67e9d5722 failed
2018-09-28 17:01:12 ERROR: ProcessNewBlock: ActivateBestChain failed
2018-09-28 17:09:07 connect() to [2003:ea:9bde:5600:1180:6df2:ba35:efd]:18333 failed: Network is unreachable (101)
2018-09-28 17:13:23 connect() to 45.55.161.7:18333 failed after select(): Connection refused (111)
2018-09-28 17:14:19 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 1841 seconds ago)
2018-09-28 17:14:24 New outbound peer connected: version: 70013, blocks=1414565, peer=24
```

It seems to me that maybe block 1414433 is orphaned. How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That block is not just orphaned, it is actually invalid. It exploits [CVE-2018-17144](https://bitcoincore.org/en/2018/09/20/notice/). The only way to fix this error is to upgrade to [Bitcoin Core 0.16.3](https://bitcoincore.org/en/releases/0.16.3/) and begin a reindex following the upgrade.

Comment: exactly as described, problem solved